# Failed to publish the request over MQTT - Flutter - Parse Server

Tags: android, flutter, parse-platform, parse-server

I have a sample app that uses Parse Server. I've been testing my app on both emulator and physical devices and I noticed that the response time is much slower on the physical device.

This one is from the emulator.[image: network logs from the emulator]

and this is one is from the physical device:[image: network logs from the physical device]

I've been scratching my head regarding this one. I've also posted it on the parse community platform and followed the advice there to manually monitor the server for every change I've made until I reach my prior server configuration. I overhauled the server from scratch. Do some load testing -> Deployed the server on a replica set -> load testing. Now, I'm in the process of doing some basic queries. I used ADB logcat to see what's happening on both device and saw these errors on the physical device and not on the emulator:

```
E[N rtchannel]_rt_mqtt_publish_callback(356)=>Failed to publish the request over MQTT. token:be925eea-407c-417d-96c9-3af5a7e83e48, category:mcd-sync-data-task-category, requestId:54138, error:Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
```

```
E[S sync]_createResponseError(166)=>Network Response be925eea-407c-417d-96c9-3af5a7e83e48 contains sync error Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008 - Underlying error (null): Error Domain=mqtt Code=3008
```

This one also shows before pulling the payload.

```
W[S sync-state-machine]MCDSyncStateMachineScheduleDelayedRetry(173)=>skipping the new retry with longer delay
```

```
W[S sync]_scheduleNextCursorRetry(326)=>skipping delayed retry due to state machine state decision
```

The number of times these errors pop up is related to the number of queries executed. I did not put any configurations on the server which use MQTT. Any help is much appreciated.